# How to configure Apache2 to allow it to read directories from other media

Tags: permissions, apache2

I'm migrating from Windows and I have some projects from there on another hard drive. And I'd like to run Apache on Ubuntu and let it run sites from Windows HDD. I tried to configure `apache2.conf` but keep failing. I made symlink in /var/www directory to directory on Windows HDD but Apache says its forbidden. This is my configuration:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   54 mar 15 13:34 /var/www/app2 -> /media/user/E874D9B0/wamp24/www/app2/
```

and in `apache2.conf` file:

```
<Directory /media/user/E874D9B0/wamp24/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

rest is standard, fresh install apache2 configuration. Should I try to configure VirtualHost?

Comment: Unfortunately VirtualHost don't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I have to run Apache as user who mounted the media I want to use. In order to do that I had to modify two lines of `apache2.conf` file.

I had to check what user have permissions to read files from `/media/user/E874D9B0/wamp24/www/app2/` with `ls -al` command. And write that user name into config file.

```
User user
Group user
```